# How to get values between two dates with a interval of 10 minutes between the dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
    t0.brandID,
    t0.brandName,
    t0.cdt,
    t0.udt,
    t0.brandstatus,
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, t0.cdt)) as tempt
FROM brands t0 
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),t0.cdt,110) BETWEEN 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'01-11-2013',110) and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'11-11-2014',110)
```

The above query giving me values between the dates. I want to get values between these dates for every 10 minutes.

```
brandID brandName   cdt                     udt                         brandstatus tempt
1       khasim      2013-11-01 19:14:18.123 2013-11-15 19:14:18.123     1           14
3       khasim      2013-11-02 19:17:57.700 2013-11-15 19:17:57.700     1           17
4       tanveer     2013-11-03 19:18:05.947 2013-11-15 19:18:05.947     1           18
5       abcdef      2013-11-04 20:50:06.783 2013-11-15 20:50:06.787     1           50
8       budwieser   2014-02-12 19:26:43.913 2014-02-12 19:26:43.913     1           26
```

expected result: (when selecting date between 15-11-2013 and 16-11-2013)

```
    brandid brandname cdt udt
    1        khasim   2013-11-15 (00:00:01)---first record created on that date
    2        somethi  2013-11-15 (00:00:05)---second record

...
...  
final record at (00:10:00) minutes...
```

need to calculate number of 10 minute intervals between selected date and for every 10 min interval need to get records.

Comment: Get datediff using minute interval and divide by 10. if this is not you answer, provide 2 dates and expected result.

Comment: Why I you converting from date to varchar to perform comparison with dates?..

Comment: the column is having timestamp

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected result?

Comment: cast to date to cut time

Comment: @Tan, can you elaborate on this: `I want to get values between these dates for every 10 minutes.`

Comment: Another approach to ignore time is to append one day to the upper date in predicate and replace `<=` comparison with `<`. Will do the same without conversions at all.

Comment: sorry but i am not worried about date. i do know that without conversion we can handle the date. but i want to show data for every ten minute interval within a given period of time.